Perl Net::OpenSSH connect to server that requires RSA & Password
I have to connect to a server that uses an RSA key as well as password to authenticate. However, I'm having an issue getting it to actually work in Net::OpenSSH.
If I try from the command line it reads the myuser's RSA and then prompts for the password (not RSA Passphrase, as that is blank for testing):
 sudo -u myuser ssh myuser@hostip

This works fine.
However, in perl it fails to connect claiming a RSA Passkey failure. "Permission denied (publickey)."
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(
  $server, 
  user => $username, 
  password => $passwd, 
  timeout => 10,
  master_opts => [-o => "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"]
);
$ssh->error and die "Unable to connect: " . $ssh->error;

I am sudoing the perl script as the same user that works successfully from the command line so it should be using its RSA key, but somehow it acts as if its not being sent at all.

To use Net::OpenSSH with a RSA key, you should use the key_path and passphrase options.
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host,
                            key_path => $keyfile,
                            passphrase => $password);
$ssh->error and
    die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
$ssh->system("ls /tmp") or
    die "remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;


The server I'm connecting to wants the users password, though, its not the RSA passphrase.
Do I still use the passphrase option in that case and just set it to the users password?

If the server allows pubkey authentication on the command line (you tested that) then it will also allow pubkey authentication with OpenSSH->new(). User password and key passphrase are usually different, and in your case, the key passphrase can be empty.
